# ¿Cómo se implementa una aplicación en una instancia de AWS con CloudFormation?

Tags: aws, deployment, ec2

Quiero desplegar [Docanno](https://github.com/doccano/doccano#user-content-fnref-1-20cb32dfdf3d81b86d76b065c087f482) en AWS para que un equipo haga el etiquetado. Así que he seguido [este enlace](https://github.com/doccano/doccano#one-click-deployment) Parece que despliega Docanno en CloudFormation, pero no sé dónde está la url para llegar a Docanno.

Answer (score 0):

Ve a tu stack de CloudFormation.

Ahí haces click sobre la pestaña "Recursos" y buscas el recurso donde se está desplegando tu servicio. Entiendo que estás desplegando Docanno en una Lambda, así que podemos tener varios escenarios:

- La lambda se ha desplegado en una IP pública: Busca la Lambda en los recursos del stack y comprueba en dicha Lambda cual es su url de acceso
- La lambda se ha desplegado en una IP privada: Si se ha desplegado un API Gateway, consulta la ruta pública de dicho gateway para ver cómo acceder a la Lambda. Si no se ha desplegado este servicio es porque deberías tener acceso directo a la Lambda a través de la VPN de la empresa

Si no estás usando una Lambda sino una instancia de EC2, tendrás que localizar la IP de dicha instancia. Nuevamente, puedes localizar esta instancia en la lista de recursos del stack de CloudFormation